# Facebook SDK 3.1.1 iOS 6 Logout in Device Settings, return to app and HTTP status code: 400 error

Tags: facebook, authentication, ios6, authorization, logout

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.1.1 in my iOS app with iOS 6. I came across this issue while testing Facebook logout from the user account in the Settings app.

Once the app is authorized for Facebook use via the Settings App for Facebook, and the user THEN goes in and deletes the Facebook connection within the Settings App (not just for this app but, but deletes username), therein lies the problem.

When I return to the app, it shows that  am still logged in. But when I try to access Facebook, I get the Error:HTTP status code:400. I have tried to close and clear the token information for the FBSession, but that does not help. I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide details for how you are clearing the token information.

You should be calling:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

When you say you are still logged in, what Facebook method is telling you this?  You should be testing with something like this:

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
    isLoggedIn = YES;
}
```